# simultaneous linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

If a pair of linear equations have infinite solutions, then does that mean they are consistent?
And first of all, what does it mean if two simultaneous equations are **consistent**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A system of equations is said to be **consistent** is it admits (at least) one solution, in particular, if a pair of linear equation has infinitely many solutions, the system formed by them is **consistent**.

*Note:* You don't say "the equations are consistent" but "the system is consistent",

Comment: @Ramana You're welcome! There probably will be some other answers, please don't forget to select an accepted one at the very end.